# jQuery plugin that deserializes XML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, serialization

Is there an XML deserializer for javascript? Preferably in the form of a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 7):

You can [manipulate XML with Javascript just like the DOM](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-and-XML/1/).

To do it with jQuery, you can just pass your XML to the jQuery function and voila, it is ready...

```
var dat = '<xml><test foo="bar">Cool!</test></xml>';
var xml = $(dat);
alert(xml.find("test").text());  // shows "Cool!"
alert(xml.find("test").attr("foo"));  // shows "bar"
```